# Qt 5.3 Qt Quick applications shows white screen

Tags: qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have downloaded the latest Qt 5.3.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8.2, OpenGL) installer.

And tried creating a test QtQuick project using Qt Creator. 
I chose File -> new project -> QtQuick Application in the Qt Creator. In the qt component set, I chose "Qt Controls 1.1" and created the default Hello World application.

When I compile and run the application, the Hello world text appears briefly and then the window becomes white.

I could not get the Qt Quick application working. 
Is it a bug in Qt 5.3 or am I doing someing wrong ? Please help.

Here is the qml file generated by Qt Creator.
main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Here is the main.cpp file generated:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Is there any error messages in Application Output window?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same behavior some time ago. It was because of x32-bit Windows systems OpenGL/DirectX mess. Just try to call `app.setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);` to force using of Angle (DirectX on Windows) instead of OpenGL. before loading your main QML file. Of course you should install Angle build of Qt framework. Since 5.5 version it is the only one which is supported.

Answer (score 0):

After windows update I find this issue seems to have got resolved. Sill I find the qtquick application hang randomly when I click on the exit button.